# Можно ли установить голый терминал Linux как операционку

Tags: linux, консоль, командная-строка

Итак: я хочу установить в качестве операционной системы - Линукс, но без графической оболочки, то есть голый терминал. Может есть готовый дистрибутив , или надо ядро вручную устанавливать, хз. Возможно ли такое сотворить, и если можно, то как(желательно в деталях, я немного тупой )?

Comment: Ubuntu Server как вариант

Comment: Или Manjaro Architect.

Comment: В принципе, Arch из коробки идёт без гуи, но у него не самый простой процесс установки.

Comment: У дебиана иксы и окружение рабочего стола нужно явно выбирать для установки (по крайней мере, это так в текстовом инсталляторе).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раньше эта задача решалась с помощью задания значения переменной *runlevel* в файле */etc/inittab*.
Простому терминалу без графики соответствовал *runlevel=3*.

Современные дистрибутивы выполняют загрузку по другому и не используют этот файл. Однако, для совместимости,
предумотрена обработка такого файла, если он присутствует.

Вот какой совет дают для *Ubuntu*:

*If you want to change the default-runlevel of your Ubuntu system and looking for the /etc/inittab go change it and see that Ubuntu lacks it, don't worry(!), to do so you you can create inittab file in /etc directory and write only the following line on it:*

```
id:3:initdefault:
```

*(you can change "3" to your intended default rullevel)*

(https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34405/file-in-ubuntu-equivalent-to-etc-inittab-file-in-redhat)

Comment: Спасибо всем кто ответил, все принял к сведению ☺️☺️